# Is gravity ALREADY quantum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, gravity, renormalization, quantum-gravity

[Padmanabhan has ultimately proposed that gravity is quantum from the beginning](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0205278), since we can rewrite

$$F=G_NMm/r^2=\dfrac{L_P^2c^3}{\hbar}Mm/r^2$$

From this viewpoint, the problem are the divergences in perturbative calculations with gravity at energies comparable to the Planck length. However, effective and perturbative calculations are complicated, sometimes string theory helps. What is the "real problem" with non-renormalizability in gravity? Is really the UV completion of gravity the only missing part? What is the relation with renormalizability if quantum is already quantum from the beginning?

Comment: We *know*, for a fact, that the Newtonian inverse-square law is an inaccurate approximation (via e.g. the precession of Mercury). Why would any variation coming from that be trustworthy at all?

Comment: one way to account for the non-renormalizability of gravity is that the particles that mediate the force (gravitons) interact between themselves, which the mediators of the electromagnetic force (photons) do not. This interaction renders gravity nonrenormalizable; the absence of it renders quantum electrodynamics renormalizable. At least this is one of the textbook explanations that  are furnished when this question comes up.

Comment: Your actual question is unrelated to Padmanabhan's claim, which is good because Padmanabhan's claim is problematic (see Emilio's comment), but it makes me think that this should be two separate questions.

Answer (score 1):

This is a general answer:

> What is the relation with renormalizability if quantum is already quantum from the beginning?

One can always  posit *" gravity is quantum"*. The effective quantized gravitational theory used in the cosmological  inflation models ( and wherever one is inspired to use it), are based on this postulate. One hopes that gravity is intrinsically quantized, and one hopes it will smoothly join up with the particle quantization models, and the relevant verb is "hopes".

Renormalization in QED and weak interactions  was the way to be able to calculate finite probability integrals to be checked with data by summing all terms of a perturbative expansion. Non renormalizable gauge theories suffer by the uncertainty of whether the values calculated following the summation of Feynman diagrams are correct or not. Non perturbative models have to be devised.

For QCD, [lattice QCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_chromodynamics#Lattice_QCD) seems to be able to compute masses for hadrons and crossections at the LHC, so it is checked against the data.

Effective gravitational quantization is checked against the CMB , and one expects that , renormalization or not, a theoretically stable quantization of gravity will be proposed any day now.

Actually , AFAIK, string theories with inherent supersymmetry, do quantize gravity and also have a niche for the standard model of particle physics, but the drawback is the huge number of possible theories. There has been no definitive proposal for a fixed string theory model.